# atomic_store function cannot store shared variables on debian10?

Tags: c

I have just started to learn atomic operation, and some basic problems are not very understood. I defined a shared variable **i** and initialized an atomic object **v**. I can read the value of the shared variable **i** with the atomic_load function, but I can't store it with the atomic_store function.Why is **i** still 10, not 100? my system is debian 10.

Update my question:
I'm sorry that I didn't describe it clearly. I'll update my question. In fact, I'm going to share variable **i** among multiple threads, so I call it shared variable **i**. Instead of using mutexes, I use atomic operations. **test_atomic.c** is just the one I use to test **atomic_xxx** function.But according to the results of **test_atomic.c**, I feel that my understanding is wrong.  The difficulty variable **i** is redundant, and the variable **v** is shared? I'm confused. Please help me. Thank you.

Pseudo code：

```
thread_1_function()
{
     ...
     //End of use
     atomic_store(&v, 1);
     ...
}
thread_2_function()
{
     ...
     atomic_store(&v, 2);
     ...
}
thread_3_function()
{
     ...
     atomic_load(&v);
     if (i == 1)  {...}
     else if (i == 2) {...} 
     ...
}
```

test_atomic.c

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdatomic.h>
  
  int main(void)
  {
      int i = 10;
      atomic_int v = 0;
  
      atomic_init(&v, i);
      atomic_load(&v);
      printf("v = %d\n", v);
 
      atomic_store(&v, 100);
      printf("i = %d\n", i);
 
 
      return 0;
  }
```

result :

```
root@debian:/home/guoyanzhang/test# gcc test_atomic.c
root@debian:/home/guoyanzhang/test# ./a.out
v = 10
i = 10
```

Comment: You are storing 100 in `v`, not `i`. Also there is nothing "shared" about variable `i`.

Comment: `atomic_load(&v, i);` - that cannot work, as `atomic_load` takes single argument. Should probably be `i = atomic_load(&v);`.

Comment: @StaceyGirl yes,it is an error.thx

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `atomic_init(&v, i)` does.  It merely initializes `v` with the value that `i` had, in a non-atomic fashion: basically it's just `v=i;`.  It doesn't magically merge the variables, nor indeed does it change `i` in any way.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge So, here, the atomic variable is v, not i?When in multithreading, the shared atomic variable is v?Do I understand correctly?

Comment: I see. V is an atomic variable, I is not.

Comment: "Shared" is an entirely separate concept from "atomic".  Either variable could be shared if it is defined globally or in a function that is higher up on the call stack from where the thread was started.  If it's in a function called after the thread started, it's not shared.  It is atomic if and only if it is declared as such: `atomic_int` is, `int` is not.  Non-atomic variables can also be shared between threads but need synchronization such as a mutex in order to access without a data race.

Comment: But yes.  `v` is atomic here and `i` is not, and no function you can call will change that.